64-bit machine not using 64-bit API output by windbg
I have a docker .Net6 memory dump which I open in WinDbg. And it displays the following message - 64-bit machine not using 64-bit API
but I opened the .netframework dump on Windows and it works properly.
I use Windows 11 and I have just installed WinDbg from the latest Windows SDK:
************* Preparing the environment for Debugger Extensions Gallery repositories **************
ExtensionRepository : Implicit
UseExperimentalFeatureForNugetShare : true
AllowNugetExeUpdate : true
NonInteractiveNuget : true
AllowNugetMSCredentialProviderInstall : true
AllowParallelInitializationOfLocalRepositories : true

EnableRedirectToV8JsProvider : false

-- Configuring repositories
   ----> Repository : LocalInstalled, Enabled: true
   ----> Repository : UserExtensions, Enabled: true

>>>>>>>>>>>>> Preparing the environment for Debugger Extensions Gallery repositories completed, duration 0.015 seconds

************* Waiting for Debugger Extensions Gallery to Initialize **************

>>>>>>>>>>>>> Waiting for Debugger Extensions Gallery to Initialize completed, duration 0.032 seconds
----> Repository : UserExtensions, Enabled: true, Packages count: 0
----> Repository : LocalInstalled, Enabled: true, Packages count: 41

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.27553.1004 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [D:\work\20240508\prod_recruit-email-receive-5bc8687556-5dc6j_20240508102921\tmp\recruit-email-receive-5bc8687556-5dc6j_20240508102921.dmp]
64-bit machine not using 64-bit API

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: srv*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Generic Unix Version 0 UP Free x64
System Uptime: not available
Process Uptime: not available
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
.......................................
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for libpthread-2.31.so
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for libcoreclr.so
libpthread_2_31!pthread_cond_wait+0x1e2:
00007f7a`fe9747b2 483d00f0ffff    cmp     rax,0FFFFFFFFFFFFF000h

Some commands can be executed correctly But !runaway won't do it
0:000> !threadpool
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for _var_beisen_logfiles_recruit-email-receive_config.log
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for _var_beisen_logfiles_recruit-email-receive_trace_internal.log
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for _var_beisen_logfiles_recruit-email-receive_trace_rollminute.log
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for _var_beisen_logfiles_recruit-email-receive_trace_security.log
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for _var_beisen_logfiles_recruit-email-receive_trace_filenotexist.log
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for _var_beisen_logfiles_recruit-email-receive_trace_perf.log
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for _var_beisen_logfiles_recruit-email-receive_trace_config.log
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for _var_beisen_logfiles_recruit-email-receive_trace.log
Using the Portable thread pool.

CPU utilization:  95%
Workers Total:    5
Workers Running:  2
Workers Idle:     3
Worker Min Limit: 1
Worker Max Limit: 32767

Completion Total:   0
Completion Free:    0
Completion MaxFree: 2
Completion Current Limit: 0
Completion Min Limit:     1
Completion Max Limit:     1000

0:000> !runaway
 User Mode Time
  Thread       Time
  134:1725     0 days 0:00:00.000
  133:1720     0 days 0:00:00.000
  132:171e     0 days 0:00:00.000
  131:16fe     0 days 0:00:00.000
  130:16d0     0 days 0:00:00.000
  129:2fb      0 days 0:00:00.000
  128:2f7      0 days 0:00:00.000
  127:13a      0 days 0:00:00.000


While the WinDbg releases over the past few years have added a whole lot of support for different kinds of dumps (e.g.: core dumps, kernel KDUMPs, etc...) and formats (e.g.: DWARF, ELF, MachO, etc...) from other platforms (e.g.: Linux, MacOS, etc...), there are, unfortunately, some messages and commands which are really only meaningful for Windows.
The "64-bit machine not using 64-bit API" can safely be ignored when the debugger is targeting non-Windows platforms.  It really should be made to not display when not targeting Windows.
The "!runaway" command is one of many debugger extensions that is still rather Windows specific.  While it can get a list of threads from the debugger on Linux, the manner in which it determines time is specific to Windows and it will end up just displaying 0 on other platforms.

Thank you very much for your reply. How should I analyze. net dump on liunx?
